# session with two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have two controllers: workers and tasks.

`views/workers/index` contains:

```
<% @workers.group_by(&:name).each do |name, workers| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= name %></td>
    <td><%= workers.size %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

It shows me all the workers and their number of tasks.

I want to add a another <**td**> that is named: "show all tasks" and shows all the tasks of worker X.

**in order to do that, I think I need something like:**

```
<td><%= link_to 'show all tasks', worker_task_path(name) %></td>
```

thus, I have `tasks_controller`:

```
def index
    @task = Worker.where(:name => params[:id]) respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @worker }
    end
end
```

and this is `views/tasks/index`:

```
<% @task.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.name %></td>
    <td><%= task.task %></td>
    <td><%= task.done %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In addition, I defined `routes.rb`:

```
TODO::Application.routes.draw do
   #resources :workers
   #root to:"workers#index"

   match '/workers/:id/index', :to => 'tasks#index', :as => 'index_task'

   resources :workers do
   resources :tasks

end
```

I think I didn't define the routes.rb correctly, because **my error is**:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tasks", :worker_id=>"alon"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could simplify your routes by removing the unnecessary `match` directive. By declaring :

```
resources :workers do
    resources :tasks
end
```

you nested the tasks resources into the workers ones. Your tasks index will then be accessible using :

```
workers/:id/tasks
```

where `id` is the primary key of your worker model.

Rails path helpers are sensitive to the singular / plural form. The  path in the `link_to` call corresponds to a specific worker (singular) containing a list of tasks (plural). Rails router expects a primary key or a model instance as the id parameter :

```
<%= link_to 'All tasks', worker_tasks_path(worker) %>
or
<%= link_to 'All tasks', worker_tasks_path(worker.id) %>
```

Comment: thank you! it almost works. my problem is (for example) that if I pressed "show tasks" of the worker Alon, I will be directed to: http://localhost:3000/workers/alon/tasks

and this page is blank and doesn't show my index page of tasks..

Comment: Rails default behavior is to use the (numeric) primary key to build paths to resources. If you want to have a friendly URL instead of the `workers/1/tasks` you may consider using the friendly_id gem : https://github.com/norman/friendly_id.